# Problem remember a nested object with gui.remember()

Tags: javascript, dat.gui

I have a nested object like this:

```
var config = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 2,
    d: 3
  }
}
```

that I use in a `dat.gui` instance:

```
var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.remember( config );

gui.add( config, 'a' );
gui.add( config.b, 'c' );
gui.add( config.b, 'd' );
```

but `dat.gui` instance only remember `config.a` (see a live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rvcristiand/cz08tLmr/4/).

Look into parameters to copy in localstorage I found that only `a` value is tracked:

```
{
  "preset": "Default",
  "remembered": {
    "Default": {
      "0": {
        "a": 9.9
      }
    }
  },
  "closed": false,
  "folders": {}
}
```

I found the same when I print out gui.getSaveObject() (I think parameters showed in the pop windows are generated with this function).

Then, there is a way to remember all object's value ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested properties don't seem to be supported, but you can remember multiple configs.

```
gui.remember( config );
gui.remember( config.b );

gui.add( config, 'a' );
gui.add( config.b, 'c' );
gui.add( config.b, 'd' );
```